# A geodesic frame problem

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Could anyone help me with it? I don`t know how to write by Latex, so I have update a picture of the problem.

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/498Sa.jpg)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/498Sa.jpg

thankyou very much!